# sphinx performance after idle

Tags: sphinx

I'm writing a web application for which I'm using [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) to search around a million documents.

The performance is excellent, with a typical query taking just 0.05 seconds, but if no queries are made for a few hours, it suddenly takes much longer - up to 1000x longer for a couple of queries, then returns to normal.  The query log looks like this:

```
[Wed Mar  7 17:23:55.937 2012] 0.221 sec 
[Wed Mar  7 17:32:00.726 2012] 0.012 sec 
[Wed Mar  7 17:32:00.984 2012] 0.052 sec 
[Wed Mar  7 17:32:01.416 2012] 0.222 sec 
[Thu Mar  8 09:15:10.418 2012] 10.147 sec
[Thu Mar  8 09:16:00.560 2012] 48.262 sec
[Thu Mar  8 09:16:55.429 2012] 54.153 sec
[Thu Mar  8 09:17:54.454 2012] 0.012 sec 
[Thu Mar  8 09:17:54.713 2012] 0.052 sec 
[Thu Mar  8 09:17:55.141 2012] 0.218 sec
```

I'm guessing maybe my busy server is swapping Sphinx's memory when it is unused or something.

How can I resolve this?

I considered scripting fake queries every minute but that seems like quite an ugly hack.

Comment: +1. Good Question. Hmm can auto warming queries over a period of time help here? Not sure.

Comment: Are you using preopen_indexes in your sphinx configuration. This tells sphinx to load the indexes in memory and not rely on the operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How fast are the disks on this server?

I imagine this due to having to go back to disk for the indexes. Once accessed a few times, the OS will have cached the files.

It might be worth considering a SSD disk. A small SSD disk - big enough for sphinxes indexs - is relativly cheap nowadays.

If it really is memory swapping, that also suggests you have slow disks. But that is also something to address. Can you add more memory to server? (or even put the swap partition on the newly installed SSD disk :)

btw, find out if swapping is happening with something like Munin (or Cacti etc)

Comment: +1 without reading the answer as barryhunter is an authority on sphinx.

Comment: Hmm, thats very nice and all. But I didnt really answer the question. Just provide possible causes - and how to upgrade to work around. The first thing is still to find the actual cause. What causes those queries to be slow.

Comment: I moved some other services off the server, thus freeing up a large amount of extra memory.  The problem went away immediately, no more slow queries.  Thanks!